# Cast SomeType<Protocol> to SomeType<ProtocolImpl> in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, casting

I'm currently experimenting with Generics in Swift and came to some problem with casting some types around such as `SomeType<Protocol>` to `SomeType<ProtocolImpl>`. So basically I have some type that takes a generic parameter which is handled as a Protocol and which at a later point is casted to a more concrete type. My question is if that isn't possible to do?

```
/// 'dict' is of type [String: SomeType<Protocol>]
if let element = dict["str"], // 'element' here is of type SomeType<Protocol>
   let castedElement = element as? SomeType<ProtocolImpl> { // This is always false
    return castedElement // Here I want to return castedElement with type SomeType<ProtocolImpl>
}
```

Is there any way to make this cast work? I'm already working on another solution for my problem, but I'm still interested if there's a way to make this work somehow.

Edit: Because @jtbandes wanted a example he can paste somewhere, here:

```
class SomeType<T> {
    let value: T

    init(value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

protocol Protocol {}

class ProtocolImpl: Protocol {}

var dict: [String: SomeType<Protocol>] = ["str": SomeType(value: ProtocolImpl())]

if let element = dict["str"],
   let castedElement = element as? SomeType<ProtocolImpl> {
    print(castedElement.value) // I want to get here
}
```

Comment: The way you've written it this isn't possible, but if you [edit] your question to include a [mre] then perhaps someone can advise you on a different solution.

Comment: You can't cast a `dict[String:type]` to `type`.  It is a dictionary containing instances of your type, but it is NOT an instance of your type, no matter how you are abstracting.

Comment: @Putz1103 nowhere in the code there is a cast from dictionary to some other type, read again closely. `dict["str"]` is of type `SomeType<Protocol>`

Comment: Why not just check if `let castedElement = element.value as? ProtocolImpl`.  That should work properly.

Comment: @Putz1103 While this would compile, this isn't my goal. I want a reference to a SomeType<ProtocolImpl> object from the array and not a ProtocolImpl object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short, generics in Swift are not covariant, which means that `SomeType< ProtocolImpl>` is not convertible `SomeType<Protocol>`, even if `ProtocolImpl` conforms to `Protocol`. Thus the direct answer to your question is: this is not currently possible in Swift.

However you might ask yourself is why do you need the downcast in the first place. As you're storing the instances in a container, polymorphic behaviour might be better suited. You could declare the functionality you need to access as part of the protocol, and access is though the protocol interface. This way you don't need to know which is the concrete implementation under the hood, which is one of the main reason of using a protocol.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I just wanted to know if it was possible to get a casted reference from the dictionary. This problem came up during work and thus I was eager to know if this would be possible. In the big scheme we already avoiding these casting problem by choosing another data structure but I still was interested, because I wanted to learn about Swift also.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard for me to tell what you're trying to achieve from the question. Still, maybe the below will help you.

```
class SomeType<T>: Protocol { // Maybe SomeType IS your ProtoImpl?
    let value: T

    init(value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

protocol Protocol {}

//class ProtocolImpl: Protocol {}

//var dict: [String: SomeType<Protocol>] = ["str": SomeType(value: ProtocolImpl())]
var dict: [String: Protocol] = ["str1": SomeType<String>(value: "Some Type"),
                                "str2": SomeType<Int>(value: 1)
                            ]

if let castedElement = dict["str1"] as? SomeType<String> {
    print(castedElement.value) // --> "Some Type"
}

if let castedElement = dict["str2"] as? SomeType<Int> {
    print(castedElement.value) // --> "1"
}
```

Comment: I should have made it clearer that my question is more theoretical rather than a problem I couldn't solve due to choosing another data structure. The actual problem involved RxSwift BehaviorRelays. I just wanted to give a very simple scenario of the problem. I appreciate your time you put into my question, thanks.